# Canadian overstay in USA

Tags: usa, overstaying, canadian-citizens

I wonder if someone can help me with this rather complicated situation.

My son is 17 and is deemed a minor. He has spent probably 9 months of the last year training as an athlete in the USA with the understanding that his coach would apply for an athlete's visa. At this point it looks like that promise is no longer going to happen.

He has overstayed by less than 180 days. A major sporting event that he wishes to compete in occurs after the 180 days overstay. After that he would return home and reapply for health coverage in Canada. I cautioned that overstaying longer than 180 days could lead to a 3 year ban, but after further research I discovered that minors are exempt from this punishment?

I am trying to determine the best course of action. If I should bring him home now and miss the sporting event or let him stay and risk a greater punishment. Any clarity on the rules would be much appreciated.

Comment: The best course of action is to obey the law, and not take advantage of the leniency of immigration law on minors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s essentially a question on whether to obey the law or not.

Comment: Mistakes happen and it was not intentional to break the law nor is any harm being done to anyone. I get conflicting information based on my research and was hoping for simply some clarity.

Comment: If I was you I would have an immigration lawyer on the phone right away. There may be ways round this, and a lawyer would probably know them.

Comment: Thank you DJClayworth for an actual helpful response.

Comment: The advice was given freely, obey the immigration laws of the USA. You chose not to see it. You don’t care much about the law, you care about the _major sporting event_. It was evident.

Comment: @Xeno72 what visa was he promised? How did he travel to the US? Does he have a record at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov? If so, what are his admission class and period of admission?

Comment: Phoog, he was promised an athlete's visa that would be valid for 5 years. He travelled to the US by plane and no he does not have a record, thanks.

Comment: @Xeno72 Leaving aside illegality, a further practical consideration is the potential impact on any future travel plans. He would have to declare the overstay on all future visa applications that request disclosure. As a Canadian citizen he will have visa-free entry to many countries as a tourist so he may not consider this important, but these things sometimes have a tendency to bite back unexpectedly (there are many examples on TSE). Eg if he wanted to apply for a student, sports or marriage(!) visitor visa to the UK. Also, I assume he would leave before he turns 18.

Comment: @Xeno72 One further thought: might the sports event require non-US citizen participants to provide proof of immigration status?

Comment: @Xeno72, please take note of our basic rule, be nice. I guess you take the advise of the people here as negative to you, but you were much stronger negative towards them. We only want to help and minimize the problems he may get in the future.

Comment: @Traveller A particular way in which this could bite is if the son becomes a professional athlete and wants to travel to whatever country the next competition is in.

Comment: @David Richerby Indeed. There’s also a risk that someone blows the whistle on him. In all honesty IMHO the downsides are not worth it and if it were my son, I’d bring him home now (possibly having first consulted a lawyer, as you suggested earlier).

Comment: He was promised an athlete visa? Nobody receives a USA nonimmigrant visa from inside the country. Visas are issued outside the country.

Comment: @ThEiLlEgAlaLiEn While true, it's common to _arrange_ for a visa (e.g., H1-B) while in the USA and then return home to have it stamped into one's passport.

Answer (score 4):

He does not accrue "unlawful presence" for the purposes of the 3/10-year bans under INA 212(a)(9)(B) while he is under 18. He will start accruing "unlawful presence" the day he turns 18. If he leaves more than 180 days after that, he will have a 3-year ban.

But not having a ban doesn't mean they will let him in in the future. The immigration officer at a future entry can deny him entry as a nonimmigrant for anything that the officer doesn't like about the person's situation, including any past overstays.